# Saving a computed Kirchhoff matrix(array) to a .txt file in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, save

I have generated a kirchhoff matrix, but it doesn't show all the values within the matrix in the cmd prompt. Is there a way to output this array into a .txt file such that all the values will be shown?

The array and what I did to produce it:

```
gnm = GNM('synthetase')
gnm.buildKirchhoff(calphas)
gnm.getKirchhoff()

array([[ 5., -1., -1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
[ -1., 7., -1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
[ -1., -1., 15., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
.........,
[ 0., 0., 0., ..., 9., -1., -1.],
[ 0., 0., 0., ..., -1., 12., -1.],
[ 0., 0., 0., ..., -1,. -1., 11.]])
```

The matrix was generated through a gaussian network model. I tried using numpy, but I don't know how to select the array and if I need to create the file first when doing np.savetxt(filename, X).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on the command line, you can use redirection:

```
python script.py > output.txt
```

This redirects output from the script to the file.

Comment: I attempted this, but it just gave me an invalid syntax error or ("name script not defined").

Comment: @user3339405 Well, substitute `script.py` with your script's name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using NumPy. If that's true, then

```
np.savetxt(filename, data)
```

(where `data` is the name of the array) should do the trick. See [the numpy.savetxt doc page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).

Comment: Do you know how to define/select the name of the array such that the above method works? Also, does the file already need to exist in the directory in order for the data to save? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use NumPy in your project, `np.savetxt()` will make your day, check usage and examples [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)